# How to spawn child thread from main thread while main thread keeps executing in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am making an application to convert audio recorded from microphone to text. The length of the recording can be very long like 3 hours, so I guessed it would be better to convert it to wave files of small durations like a minute or so and subsequently spawn a child thread where that audio to text operation is carried out, whereas the main thread can start recording for the next minute. The audio to text operation is way faster than the recording part so timing won't be an issue.

[image: flowchart]

This is a flowchart of how I think it should work.

I am using `pyaudio` for recording the audio. It's code:

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import time

def read_audio(stream):
    chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
    seconds = 10
    filename = 'record.wav'
    frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames
    # Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
    
    for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)
    
    # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
    
    # Stop and close the stream
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

    

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio
chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 2
fs = 44100
stream = p.open(format=sample_format,channels=channels,rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,input=True)
read_audio(stream)
p.terminate() # Terminate the PortAudio interface
```

For speech recognition, Google's API `speech_recognition` is used. Its code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def convert():
    sound = "record.wav"
 
    r = sr.Recognizer()
 
 
    with sr.AudioFile(sound) as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Converting Audio To Text and saving to file..... ") 
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:

        value = r.recognize_google(audio) ##### API call to google for speech recognition

        if str is bytes: 
            result = u"{}".format(value).encode("utf-8")

        else: 
            result = "{}".format(value)

        with open("test.txt","a") as f:
            f.write(result)
        print("Done !\n\n")

    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("{0}".format(e))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
 
convert()
```

Comment: How will your main thread know not to start and stop the recording in the middle of a spoken word?  If, as you say, the speech-to-text algorithm runs "way faster" than real time, then maybe you can figure out a way to _stream_ the audio, instead of storing and processing a chunk at a time.

Comment: @SolomonSlow, this program is to proctor students throughout the exams, so there is an assumption that they would not be speaking much, so stopping in the middle of a word can be ignored. Applying `speech_recognition` on the audio from the microphone requires continuous speech and it stops after a pause so I had to resort to storing the audio and then processing it.

Comment: Considering that the converting part of this code also takes a little time, how opposed would you be to there being 3 threads? 1 that controls a thread which records, and another thread which converts the audio to text.

There would still be a delay if converting the audio isn't ran in another thread.

Comment: I am fine with any number of threads as long as it gets the work done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is never truly multithreaded because of the GIL, however that probably doesn't matter in your case because you are using an api call to do the speech recognition for you.

So you could try this to start a thread to do the conversion

```
from threading import Thread
t = Thread(target=convert)
t.start()
```

and before you try to convert your next minute you might try to join the last thread to make sure that it has finished

```
t.join()
```

You could probably also use the asyncio library

Although it might be overkill I would probably use the multiprocessing library. In your case you could have a *listener worker* process that is constantly recording and saving new sound files, and a *conversion worker* process which is constantly looking for new files and converting them.

This would allow for you to write a more robust system if you need to. For example if you lost internet connection and couldn't convert your sound files through the google api for a few minutes the *recorder worker* would just keep on saving out sound files without caring which would get processed when the internet connection is restored.

Anyways, here is a little example of a conversion worker process you could use.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

class ConversionWorker:

    def __init__(self, sound_file_directory_path: str, text_save_filepath: str):
        self.sound_directory_path = Path(sound_file_directory_path)
        self.text_filepath = Path(text_save_filepath)

    def run(self):
        while True:

            # find and convert all wav files in the target directory
            filepaths = self.sound_directory_path.glob('*.wav')
            for path in filepaths:
                # convert from path
                # save to self.text_filepath
                convert()

                # we can delete the sound file after converting it
                os.remove(path)

            # sleep for a bit since we are only saving files once a minute or so
            sleep(5)

def main():
    conversion_worker = ConversionWorker(sound_file_directory_path='path/to/sounds', text_save_filepath='path/to/text')
    p = mp.Process(target=conversion_worker.run)
    p.start()

    # do the recording and saving for as long as you want

    p.terminate()
```

Comment: So what you are basically suggesting is that I create a directory and keep on adding wav files in it. Along with this I start a different process (or thread) and use the speech api to convert whatever the files are there and maybe delete those process to sav space?

Comment: yeah, that is what I would probably do at least. Like you said just dump the wav files into a directory and have a separate process that just checks for and coverts the files every once and while. But there are number of different ways you could solve this though, including just spawning a thread like i mentioned at the beginning of the post.

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty as it helped me in achieving the solution which I have posted as an answer if anyone is stuck.

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solving this question was inspired by Jeremy Bare. I decided to post an answer on how I finally did it so if someone wants to do a similar thing, then they can have the complete code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
import wave
import time
import threading
import os

def read_audio(stream, filename):
    chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
    seconds = 10 # Number of seconds to record at once
    filename = filename
    frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames
    
    for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        frames.append(data)
    
    # Save the recorded data as a WAV file
    wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
    wf.setnchannels(channels)
    wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
    wf.setframerate(fs)
    wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wf.close()
    # Stop and close the stream
    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()

def convert(i):
    if i >= 0:
        sound = 'record' + str(i) +'.wav'
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        
        with sr.AudioFile(sound) as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
            print("Converting Audio To Text and saving to file..... ") 
            audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            value = r.recognize_google(audio) ##### API call to google for speech recognition
            os.remove(sound)
            if str is bytes: 
                result = u"{}".format(value).encode("utf-8")
            else: 
                result = "{}".format(value)
 
            with open("test.txt","a") as f:
                f.write(result)
                f.write(" ")
                f.close()
                
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            print("")
        except sr.RequestError as e:
            print("{0}".format(e))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio
chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 2
fs = 44100

def save_audios(i):
    stream = p.open(format=sample_format,channels=channels,rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,input=True)
    filename = 'record'+str(i)+'.wav'
    read_audio(stream, filename)

for i in range(30//10): # Number of total seconds to record/ Number of seconds per recording
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=save_audios, args=[i]) 
    x = i-1
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=convert, args=[x]) # send one earlier than being recorded
    t1.start() 
    t2.start() 
    t1.join() 
    t2.join() 
    if i==2:
        flag = True
if flag:
    convert(i)
    p.terminate()
```

The `read_audio()` and `convert()` functions are nearly the same as posted in the question, however, they now take an integer as an argument. This is useful to determine the file number they will be working on in that particular thread.

As recording has to be done first, the speech recognition function is passed a value of one less than the integer provided to the recording function. This ensures it works only on the recorded audios.